# Java Sudoku Solver, does it work the same with different sudoku sizes?

Tags: java

I have a sudoku solver that works with 9x9 sudokus perfectly. I would like to get it to work with 9x6 sudokus and other sizes too. Is it possible to just change this function?

You can see that the "9" is always hardcoded. So I tried changing these values to 9 and 6 but the result is only 0s in my solution.

So before I continue messing around with this, is it even possible to change this to support different grid sizes without changing the functions?

```
    public boolean solve(int i, int j, int[][] cells) {

        if (i == 9) {
            i = 0;
            if (++j == 9) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (cells[i][j] != 0)
        {
            return solve(i + 1, j, cells);
        }

        for (int val = 1; val <= 9; ++val) {
            if (legal(i, j, val, cells)) {
                cells[i][j] = val;
                if (solve(i + 1, j, cells)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        cells[i][j] = 0;
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean legal(int i, int j, int val, int[][] cells) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 9; ++k) // rij
        {
            if (val == cells[k][j]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < 9; ++k) // kolom
        {
            if (val == cells[i][k]) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        int boxRowOffset = (i / 3) * 3;
        int boxColOffset = (j / 3) * 3;
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) // box
        {
            for (int m = 0; m < 3; ++m) {
                if (val == cells[boxRowOffset + k][boxColOffset + m]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: I don't see how a Sudoku puzzle *can* have a different number of rows than columns...

Comment: Sudoku puzzle always got AxA but never AxB in size. you can try 3x3, 6x6, 9x9, 12x12, 15x15, 18x18 and so on

Comment: Well, you can have all kinds of [shapes](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sudoku+different+shapes&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAybuhzPnTAhVL2SwKHcaFDh4QsAQILw&biw=1703&bih=878) for such number puzzles. But then I wouldnt call it a sudoku any more ...

Comment: I have never seen a 9x6 sudoku but I don't see why OP couldn't govern and code some rules for it.

Comment: to make it more dynamic try replacing `9` with `cells.length`.  You'll also need some way to determine the size of  box.

Comment: Though when using larger than 9x9 you'd need to use a different numbering system from the normal decimal system. It might also be limited to square numbers. So for example 4x4, 9x9, 16x16, 25x25 to be a proper sudoku.

Comment: Oh god, seems like I mixed up box size with sudoku size... I want to solve 3x2 & 2x3 sudokus as in box size. So the sudoku will be 6x6 then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most primitive sudoku is a 2x2 sudoku

```
1 2
2 1
```

You have excaclty two solutions and every number is present in every row and every number is present in every column.

Another example is a 3x2

```
1 2
2 3
3 1
```

This is not solvable because not all numbers are present in every row.

Also a 9x6 will not have every number present in every row.

Therefore no solution is possible and this is not a sudoku.